# after angular $save and push to array item is not added unless I re-run a query

Tags: arrays, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, angular-resource

I have a single page app built using the MEAN stack. I am trying to get a list of items to update after a new item is added in angular but it's not working.

```
$scope.storages = Storages.query();
```

This works fine and returns my array of storages that I display in the view.

I then have a field to add a new array... to simplify the code it looks like this:

```
// create a new storage object from $scope.newStorage
var storage = new Storages($scope.newStorage);
```

I then do various things to the data and finally...

```
storage.$save(function(){

  $scope.storages.push(storage); // doesn't seem to do anything
  console.log("new storage", storage); //shows up fine
  $scope.newStorage = []; // clear textbox
  $scope.showHide.addItemPanel = false; // hides the newStorage form
  return $scope.storages;
});
```

It seems like `$scope.storages.push(storage)` is not doing anything.

If I use this code at the end:

```
$scope.storages = Storages.query();
return $scope.storages;
```

Then it works. But I don't want to have to keep getting all the data from the server each time. How can I solve this and why isn't this working?

If I `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.storages))` it looks like this:

```
[{"_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","_title":"XXXXXXXXX","__v":0,"files":[],"comments":[],"fields":[{"0":{"Title":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX"},"1":{"Category":"coding"},"2":{"Details":"XXXXXXXXX
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you confirm that $scope.storages is an array ? Also, what shows if you try to `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.storages))`?

Comment: What is "Storages"? Is that your own class or is that something from a Mongo/Angular client library you're using?

Comment: @ionelPOP when I `console.log($scope.storages)` it says it's an `Array [Object, Object, etc.]` ... I've added a snippet of the JSON.stringify output above.

Comment: @yourfriendzak "Storages" is an angular resource produced through a factory: ` .factory('Storages', ['$resource', function($resource){ return $resource('/storages/:id', null, { 'update': { method:'PUT' }  }); }])`

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments below

```
storage.$save(function(){

  //storage is promise here, not a Storage object you expect
  $scope.storages.push(storage);

  //because console.log binds to reference
  //so after promise resolves, value on reference is changed
  console.log("new storage", storage); //shows up fine

  //not required at all
  return $scope.storages;
});
```

Simple solution

```
//bind this to $scope
var storage = new Storages($scope.newStorage); 

//like this
$scope.storage = new Storages($scope.newStorage);
//so Resource.$save is promise, when it completes, it will trigger digest
//and your array will be populated
$scope.storage.$save();
$scope.newStorage = [];
$scope.showHide.addItemPanel = false;
$scope.storages.push($scope.storage);
```

Better solution

```
//$save accepts callback
storage.$save(function(newStorageFromServer){

  //newStorageFromServer is not promise, but actual result from server
  //which is Storage instance by default
  $scope.storages.push(newStorageFromServer);

  //other staff
  $scope.newStorage = []; // clear textbox
  $scope.showHide.addItemPanel = false; // hides the newStorage form

  //return statement is useless
});
```

Comment: :( no luck, I'm afraid. It still doesn't show up until I run the query again.

Comment: OK. So it has all become clear now I think. The returned object has a field that is populated by mongoose on the server side that doesn't show up on the returned promise... that's why it doesn't show up... now need to figure out how to make that happen...? any thoughts?